# Import Error SciPy Python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

I am new to Python and I am trying to perform numerical integration with the scipy library. After figuring out how to download scipy and numpy, I got the following error trying to run my code:

ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

I did some research on this, and found that it has to be because one of the packages I downloaded is not running on 32 bit. I downloaded the 32-bit version of PyCharm 2.7 from JetBrains, and the 32-bit of numpy and the 32-bit of scipy from Source Forge. I am not sure how to locate and fix the error. Please help.

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/jacob/PycharmProjects/451/test1", line 2, in 
    from scipy.integrate import quad

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate__init__.py", line 7, in 
    from quadrature import *

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadrature.py", line 5, in 
    from scipy.special.orthogonal import p_roots

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\special__init__.py", line 9, in 
    from _cephes import *

ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Perhaps you should load a more comprehensive Python distribution, one that includes scipy and numpy and most other packages you might want. I have used Anaconda2 followed by Anaconda3 to good effect, and both come in 32 and 64 bit distributions.

Comment: Rory, thanks! Anaconda works perfectly